# Excel VBA: Input box with control characters

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I'm using an input box to retrieve QR-codes from reader.

Unfortunately, the parameters in the QR-code are separated by group separator characters (decimal ASCII code 29) and these characters are being omitted.

The read in string contains all the data, but I can't distinguish the single parameters anymore.

What can I do? Is there another way to read in a string WITH all the control characters?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Without further action your inputbox result indeed gets displayed as string without (visible) `Chr(29)` group separators ... even though the `InputBox` string result still contains those characters.

Therefore you need to convert the input eventually; the following Example demonstrates possible ways:

```
Sub testInput()
'a) Provide for QR results
    Dim qr(0 To 2) As Variant
'b) Provide for default using Chr(29) group delimiters
    Dim DefaultInput
    DefaultInput = "a" & Chr(29) & "b" & Chr(29) & "c" & vbNewLine
    
'c) Execute InputBox (and assign to first QR result)
    qr(0) = "0. Visible Input:    " & InputBox("Enter QR", "QR input", DefaultInput)
'd) Convert visible inputs to 2nd and 3rd QR result
    qr(1) = "1. Replaced Chr(29): " & Replace(qr(0), Chr(29), ",")
    qr(2) = "2. Splitted Chr(29): " & Join(Split(qr(0), Chr(29)), "|")
'e) Show all three QR results
    MsgBox Join(qr, vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

**Further hint**

If you need to get the different group results separately, I'd choose the **split** function *(without joining the 0-based 1-dimensional array elements immediately, which was only done for display in the messagebox)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work. I already checked with "debug.print len(string)" and saw that the input box function just omits the group separator sign. The displayed length is the lenght of the entered string minus the count of group separator signs.

Comment: How do you input the relevant strings? I assumed to take the proposed default entry. Possibly one should change the method; can try if you edit some more code. @Thomas

Comment: I input them via a barcode reader - and this device acts like a keyboard. You can try this: Press the alt-key and 029 on your keyboard and e.g. notepad++ shows the special character "GS" (group separator) but when you do this in an input box, the "GS" character is not received. Is there another way to receive keypresses in Excel?

Comment: As I demonstrated by the default input, a inputbox should be able to return control chars - *if read in*; what I don't know is how the data transfer is executed in detail. Can't you get the data to a file or text stream and analyze them eventually? Don't know if [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) would help in a modal input function like `InputBox` (possibly the same for `Application.InputBox`). @Thomas

Comment: I can reproduce this:
When I press alt-029 in notepad++, it shows a "GS" character.
When I do the same at the input box, Excel puts out a bell sound, but the character is not being put into the string.
I believe, there is no need to analyze the string further via a file etc., because I see that the string length is not gettinig bigger when I enter a GS character into the text field (by typing alt - 029) or by using the scanner. Do you think, I could really see more in a file? Thank you!

Comment: Don't know if this could give you the idea: Define a hidden cell with formula `=CHAR(29)` and copy it manually. If you press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> anywhere within your input the Chr(29) character isn't displayed, but your inputs will contain the control character(s) as shown in my primitive example code. @Thomas